# cohomology homomorphism induced by classifying map

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\xi=(E,p,B)$ be an $n$-dimensional vector bundle.

Let $f: B\to G_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ be the classifying map.

Let $f^*: H^*(G_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty),\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2[w_1,\cdots,w_n]\to H^*(B,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ be the induced cohomology ring homomorphism.

What can we say about $f^*$?

Is it possible that $f^*=0$, i.e, maps everything to $0$?

Does $f^*$ have to be surjective?

Comment: Dear RSQ, I'm glad you have a question not about H-spaces. :) That said, you can stop tagging these algebraic geometry? :) That is, unless i am missing some algebro-geometric connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^{\ast}$ is precisely the map that sends each universal Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1, w_2, \dots w_n$ to the actual Stiefel-Whitney classes of the bundle $E$. It must map the identity to the identity (so $f^0 : H^0 \to H^0$ can never be zero), but other than that, it can certainly map all of the $w_i$ to $0$; this is equivalent to the condition that the Stiefel-Whitney classes of $E$ vanish, and holds, for example, whenever $E$ is stably trivial. In particular there is no reason for $f^{\ast}$ to be surjective.